# How do I fetch data and use it in useEffect()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to fetch data from an API and set a state with the data, but when I use the data in a child component, I get an `[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'data.name')]` warning.

Here is a gist of what I'm trying to do. Does anyone know why this might be occurring? I assume it's because the data isn't received from the API. I have tried adding an "isLoading" state and only returning the ChildComponent if it's false, but I still get the same warning (this might be because setNewProp in useEffect isn't updating when it receives the data from the API).

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const [newProp, setNewProp] = useState();
        const fetchData = async () => {
                new DataService.retrieveData().then((response) => {
                        setData(response);
                }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
                fetchData();
                setNewProp({ data, ...props });
        }, []);

        return (
                <ChildComponent newProp={newProp} />

        );
}
```

Comment: you haven't called fetchData anywhere

Comment: DataService.retrieveData() calls fetch. We have separate files specific to making API calls that we import into the component.

Comment: how? that would imply a circular/infinite call. As it's written, `fetchData` calls `DataService.retrieveData()`, not the other way around

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. Let me change the OP. fetchData is called in useEffect().

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use an async function inside an useEffect lifecycle event. As a good solution i would recommend to fully utilize the useEffect hook and use it as an effect to the updated data.

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => {
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const [newProp, setNewProp] = useState();

        const fetchData = async () => {
                new DataService.retrieveData().then((response) => {
                        setData(response);
                }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
                fetchData();
        }, []);

        useEffect(() => {
                setNewProp({ data, ...props });
        }, [data]);

        return (
                <ChildComponent newProp={newProp} />

        );
}
```

I also want to point out that useEffect runs AFTER the first render. That means your ChildComponent will always receive "undefined" as first props, since there is no initial value set at:

```
const [newProps, setNewProp] = useState(); // initial value comes here to prevent errors
```

Comment: It is correct, must use two useEffects like this, upvoted...

Comment: yep, I missed that the first one also had to be in `useEffect`. this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you have missed the `await` that is needed in `useEffect()` to make the code wait until that fetch has finished:

Before:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
  setNewProp({ data, ...props });
}, []);
```

After:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await fetchData();
    setNewProp({ data, ...props });
  })();
}, []);
```

Note that `useEffect()` doesn't support async functions (because it needs the return value to be a cleanup function, or undefined. For example, see [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/handling-api-calls-using-async-await-in-useeffect-hook-990fb4ae423).

BUT even better might be something like:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
const fetchData = async () => {
  new DataService.retrieveData().then((response) => {
    setData(response);
  }
}

fetchData();
if (data) {
  const newProp = { data, ...props };
}
```

Comment: Doing so gives me "Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function" error. Adding await in front of `new DataService.retrieveData()` also doesn't change anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest change also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you first call fetchData function, which calls a useState hook when it's done. Since useState hook works asynchronously, the state `data` will not be changed right after.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();                     // Called setData()
    setNewProp({ data, ...props });  // At this point, data hasn't changed yet.
}, []);
```

So you can use useEffect hook again to watch for changes in your `data` state. Then you should set the new state of your `newProp`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        await fetchData();
    })();
}, []);    


useEffect(() => {
    setNewProp({...props, data });
}, [data]);
```