# Set state function is not properly updating the state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
const component = () => {
        const [data, setData] = useState(null);
        const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                        new DataService().getData().then((response) => {
                                setData(response);
                                console.log(data);
                                console.log(response);
                        }
                } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                }
        }

        useEffect(() => {
                fetchData();
        }, []);
}
```

Why does console.log(data) display null even though console.log(response) displays the correct data? The data state should've been set before I console.log'd it, no?

Comment: I explained this to you on your last question. Check out my answer
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62702594/9330290

Comment: I slightly modified the implementation because nothing was working. I currently have the implementation above, but it doesn't seem like data ever changes.

Answer (score 0):

> The data state should've been set before I console.log'd it, no?

**No.**

Comment: To be more clear - `data` variable will consist of the data from response on the next page render.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because **setData** is asynchronous. Since you're immediately asking for the value of **data** after using **setData** it's likely that the value hasn't had the chance to update yet.

If you're a Chrome user, have you used React Developer Tools? This will allow you to check the state of a component without needing to rely on console.log.

Comment: I'm passing data as a prop into a child component that's the component shown above's return statement, but data never gets updated (i.e. it is always null). Why is this?

Comment: What you're using is called a "hook" which essentially offers the same usability as "setState" from a class based component. You're properly using the hook, but using `console.log` as a debugging method has it's flaws. Since `setData` (which acts like `setState`) is asynchronous, calling `console.log` immediately after results in your problem. I'm not sure what shape your response is in, but try returning some JSX with the information from `data` and you'll likely see what you're looking for.